# How can I omit columns based on a value and paste the results in a new sheet with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

My VBA is quite rusty and I'm struggling to build this macro out

I'm looking to create a button macro to omit a few columns where header values are equal to `-` and paste the results into a new sheet.

My concern is I'm not sure how to make it so that the macro doesn't just omit the column and leave a blank column in the omitted columns place, though.

I've seen methods that set the columns as an array. However, this document has ~100 active columns, and I'm unsure how to curate an array efficiently with this many columns.

Thanks in advance!
Stuck

Comment: Loop the columns?

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Excel Version 2201

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hello there Stuck, I made this code based on your request and since I could probably need it in the near future, or someone else will.**

I tested the code with **600 columns** with **10 rows** each and took about **1.30 seconds** to finish, where 300 columns had header = "-" and the other 300 were columns with random header names.

> There is no trick here, just using
> [Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells) -which only finds cells that
> are not hidden- should do the work, the rest is just normal steps.

Tell me if it worked for you since it could need some fixes to match your sheet model. Greatings!

```
   Sub test()
      Dim Rng_ As Range
      Dim Sheet_ As Worksheet
      
      
        'Disable animations while running
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        
        
      
        'Get CurrentRegion (Cells(1,1) is the same as Range("A1"))
        Set Rng_ = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        Rng_.Select
        
        
        'Get Headers row (Change it to the row where your headers are)
        Set Headers_ = Rng_.Rows(1)
        Headers_.Select
        
        
        'Hide headers = "-"
        For Each Header_ In Headers_.columns
            If Header_ Like "-" Then
                Set Column_ = Rng_.columns(Header_.Column)
                If Not (Column_.Hidden) Then Column_.Hidden = True
            End If
        Next
    
    
        'Get SpecialCells = xlCellTypeConstants
        On Error Resume Next
        Set Content_ = Nothing
        Set Content_ = Rng_.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        Content_.Select
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        
        'Create a new sheet
        If Not Content_ Is Nothing Then
            Set Workbook_ = Workbooks(Rng_.Parent.Parent.Name)
            Set Sheet_ = Workbook_.Sheets(Rng_.Parent.Name)
            Set Worksheet2_ = Workbook_.Worksheets.Add(after:=Sheet_)
            Worksheet2_.Name = Sheet_.Name & " | Filtered"
            Worksheet2_.Tab.Color = rgbCornflowerBlue                   'Add some color (life is colorful)
        
            'Paste the results into new sheet
            Content_.Copy Destination:=Worksheet2_.Cells.Range("A1")
        
        End If
    
    
    End Sub
```